# Access Violation (Segmentation Fault) error

Tags: c++

when i run my simple array coding, Access Violation (Segmentation Fault) error is appear when i enter 7th number.
How to overcome this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
  int size = 0;
  double temp[size];
  double sum = 0;
  double avg;

  cout<<"Enter how many number would you like to type: ";
  cin>>size;

  for (int i=0; i < size; ++i  ) 
  {
    cout<<endl<<"Number "<< i + 1<<": ";
    cin>>temp[i];
    sum=sum+temp[i];
  }

  avg=sum/size;

  cout <<endl<< "The sum of the array elements is: " << sum << endl;
  cout << "The average of the array elements is: " << avg << endl<<endl;

  system("pause");
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your code is not valid C++. Teach your compiler to be stricter (warnings?) and you'll be a better man for it.

Comment: Also use a debugger.

Comment: `double temp[size]` - fyi, that doesn't change when `size` changes later.

Comment: Get rid of array. It brings no good but many harm.

Comment: If you know how to deal with an array it can be good. If I would know how many items I need, I would always choose an array over any std container...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other comments explain `tmp[]` in your case has size 0 as it is initialized with the non const expression `size`. The segfault then occurs as you access memory outside the bounds of the array (c++ doesn't verify array bounds).

Why do you need the array anyhow? You can reassign the variable...

```c++
int main()
{   
  int size = 0;
  double temp;
  double sum = 0;
  double avg;

  cout<<"Enter how many number would you like to type: ";
  cin>>size;

  for (int i=0; i < size; ++i  ) 
  {
    cout<<endl<<"Number "<< i + 1<<": ";
    cin>>temp;
    sum=sum+temp;
  }
```

Alternatively you should use `vector<double> tmp`
which can adapt its size at runtime...

Answer (score 2):

No aspect of

```
int main() {
    int size = 0;
    double temp[size];
```

is valid C++. If your compiler compiles it, there's no way to predict based on the C++ language standard what the resulting program will look like, or how it will behave. Arrays (strictly speaking: complete array types) must have a strictly positive bound that is given by a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate an array like that, its size is fixed and must be known at compile time. In general, you can't use a variable for the size, however in this case, since `size` is initialized with a constant expression immediately before, its value *is* known at compile time. The compiler is effectively replacing `double temp[size]` with `double temp[0]` (maybe a warning here would be nice). Clearly, an array of (fixed) size 0 isn't going to behave nicely when you try and access its elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to dynamically allocate the array size and your approach is incorrect, Segmentation fault occurs when you are trying to access an invalid address from the memory, means the location of the array is nonexistent. I hope this solves your issue:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int size;
  int sum = 0;
  float avg;

  std::cout << "Number of elements you want to input: ";
  std::cin >> size;

  int *array = new int[size]; //assign array size dynamically

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //find sum
  {
      std::cout << "Input val " << i << ": ";
      std::cin >> array[i];
      sum = sum + array[i];
  }

  avg = sum / size; //cal avg

  cout <<endl<< "Sum: " << sum << endl; //display
  cout << "Avg: " << avg << endl;

  delete [] array; //free memory

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me. your code really help me understanding using dynamic array.